# In Ghost Stories Black Secret what is the balance between the Taoists and Wu-Feng?

Tags: ghost-stories

We played one game with this expansion on *normal*, feeling pretty confident that we can beat *normal* most times and the Wu-Feng player absolutely destroyed us. It feels like even on the easiest setting we would not stand a chance.

My question is, what is the balance between the two sides? How often should the Taoists be expected to win? Let's assume Wu-Feng has as much experience as the other players.

Also is there anything in setup that can even the odds and create a more balanced game?

Here is the basic breakdown of what we did. We had 3 Taoists. We did not have a red player and that may have been our mistake. Wu-Feng was able to focus dropping only ghost that had impact, and took away our resources. Any ghosts that would give us a break were instead dropped as curses or demons. The game was busted wide open when Wu-Feng got to haunt the key tiles directly with no chance of us to do anything about it. Once from rolling a curse die, once from doing it directly. We quickly got caught up defending our tiles, and instead got overrun, quickly seeing 3 flipped.

Comment: It looks like you are not the only one: https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/369624/negative-review-co-op-fan

Comment: @ToonKrijthe to be clear, this looks like feedback on the main game, which I do not think is too difficult for a good coop. It's with the Black Secret expansion, and a human working against the other players who would get better, as we get better, where I had trouble understanding if we could ever win..